# Python If statement in view using queryset

Tags: django

I'm attempting to use the following if statement which will display an empty set if the reportaccess is equal to All Reports using the following.

```
if reportaccess == 'All Reports':
    bhreportgrouplist = None
    cereportgrouplist = None
    finreportgrouplist = None
    careportgrouplist = None
    pireportgrouplist = None
    screportgrouplist = None
    dssreportgrouplist = None
    psgreportgrouplist = None
    othreportgrouplist = None

else:
    bhreportgrouplist = QvReportList.objects.filter(~Q(report_id__in= reportIds)).filter(report_group_id = 200)
    cereportgrouplist = QvReportList.objects.filter(~Q(report_id__in= reportIds)).filter(report_group_id = 500)
    finreportgrouplist = QvReportList.objects.filter(~Q(report_id__in= reportIds)).filter(report_group_id = 600)
    careportgrouplist = QvReportList.objects.filter(~Q(report_id__in= reportIds)).filter(report_group_id = 800)
    pireportgrouplist = QvReportList.objects.filter(~Q(report_id__in= reportIds)).filter(report_group_id = 1100)
    screportgrouplist = QvReportList.objects.filter(~Q(report_id__in= reportIds)).filter(report_group_id = 1200)
    dssreportgrouplist = QvReportList.objects.filter(~Q(report_id__in= reportIds)).filter(report_group_id = 1300)
    psgreportgrouplist = QvReportList.objects.filter(~Q(report_id__in= reportIds)).filter(report_group_id = 1400)
    othreportgrouplist = QvReportList.objects.filter(~Q(report_id__in= reportIds)).filter(report_group_id = 99999)
```

When the view goes through it is always displaying the Else, but when I view the print of reportaccess it displays as :

```
 <QuerySet ['All Reports']>
```

Why is my if condition not being met?  How can I make it met

Comment: What is creating reportaccess? How is that variable being assigned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The check for `if reportaccess == 'All Reports'` does not return `True` because, from your print, `reportaccess` is a Queryset, and you are comparing it to a string, which will never be equal.

You can verify this by running

```
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet
isinstance(reportaccess, QuerySet)
```

It seems like what you want is to check if your Queryset `reportaccess` contains 'All Reports', so something like this:

```
something = 'All Reports'
if something in reportaccess:
    #do stuff
```